# Changing size parameters in seaborn without any success

Tags: seaborn, jupyter

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")    
p1 = sns.countplot(x='sex',data=tips)
```

No matter what size adjustments I try to make by adding the height parameter or aspect, this is how it appears in Jupyter. Any idea how to change this? I am following a tutorial and in the video tutorial it appears fine, just not for me.

Comment: It works for me fine. Do you have your browser settings zoomed too high? Or is it your system? You can rule things out by running where I just ran it. Go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and press the `launch binder` button. Then when the session comes up make a cell and put your code in. If you still have the large type than it is your browser settings somehow. Is it only seaborn? Basic matplotlib plots okay? Minor thing: check your code works when posting it. For example, here you also needed `import seaborn as sns` and `tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")`.

Comment: Thanks - it works fine on binder and even on another fresh notebook, rest of the plots are all fine and my browser settings don't have any specific zoom. I guess it's just an anomaly and I need to make a fresh notebook should it happen again. Thanks for the help.